# How to create an invisible dummy page in Wagtail?

Tags: wagtail, invisible, wagtail-pageurl

How can I create an invisible dummy page in Wagtail?

I need a "virtual" page object within Wagtail to build a menu for non Wagtail based pages and also external resources. (See my entry post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935113/how-to-add-multi-level-menu-support-to-wagtail-with-support-for-non-wagtail-bas/56936761?noredirect=1#comment100477787_56936761))

```
class MenuDummyPage(Page):

    menu_description    = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    menu_icon           = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    menu_link           = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    settings_panels = [
        FieldPanel('menu_description'),
        FieldPanel('menu_icon'),
        FieldPanel('menu_link'),
    ]

    def get_sitemap_urls(self):
        return []

    def serve(self, request):
        pass
```

If I create the above page object then it is not listed within the generated wagtail sitemap.

But if I navigate on my own to that page manually the object is called. How can I stop this?

Example:
If I create a MenuDummyPage with the title "This is a test" then the system will automatically generate a slug => "this-is-a-test".

If I call "/this-is-a-test"/ in my browser wagtail is answering because the slug exists. How can I remove this behavior for my "MenuDummyPage" objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you mean by a dummy page is a page under which other pages are kept in the page tree, then you could do the following:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class Node(Page):

    subpage_types = [your subpage types]
    parent_page_types = [your parent page types]

    link = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank='True')

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('link')
    ]  

    def serve(self, request):
        if self.link is not None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.link)
        # To handle the situation where someone inadvertantly lands on a parent page, do a redirect
        first_descendant = self.get_descendants().first()
        if first_descendant:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(first_descendant.url)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.site.root_page.url)
```

The optional `link` field allows you to define a link if you wish for this position in the page tree structure.  The above, again, assumes that you are using this `Page`-based item as a placeholder in the `Page` tree so that you can have other `Page`s under it.  As long as you don't render the url of this page in your template, then users should never know how to get to the url for the `Node`, but if someone does get to the url for a `Node`-type page, then the `first_descendant` logic handles this situation by sending them to either the first descendant of the `Node` or to the home page if no descendants of `Node` exist.

In your template (note the use of [`specific_class`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/reference/pages/model_reference.html?highlight=specific#methods-and-properties)):

```
{% for item in menu_items %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% if item.specific.link and item.specific.link != '' %}{{ item.specific.link }}{% elif item.specific_class == 'Node'%}#{% else %}{% pageurl item %}{% endif %}">{{ item.title }
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. This will of course work. But would be nice if someone could tell how to prevent wagtail to add this page to his internal urls.

Comment: The Wagtail docs talk about a page tree (made up of `Page`-derived models:  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/reference/pages/theory.html?highlight=tree#nodes-and-leaves).  The definition for `Page`:  `class Page(AbstractPage, index.Indexed, ClusterableModel, metaclass=PageBase):`.  You MIGHT be able to do what you want by creating your own `Page`-like model from which to derive pages and then a `Node` model (duplicating the `Page` definition except for the slug functionality), but then you'd be rewriting Wagtail - and I'm doubtful this could be done successfully.  I'd keep it simple as above.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I will keep it as you described it here.